# How to open an XML file in utf-16 encoding in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would love to help with expressing that I've been here for a few weeks.

**I'm trying to open an XML file in Perl in encoding utf-16.**

I am able to create the file in utf-8 but it does not suit me and more than that it causes me problems.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you opening the XML file? Also, you might want to look at the documentation for [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [PerlIO](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) on how to deal with encoding.

Comment: See [ENCODINGS-SUPPORT in XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0201/LibXML.pod#ENCODINGS-SUPPORT-IN-XML::LIBXML)

Comment: I want to create an xml file and write to it by printing to it or writing, but I need the file to be encoded in Utf-16LE format

Comment: Please visit the following [webpage](https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/05/perlunicook-specify-a-files-encoding.html/) to learn how to specify file encoding.

Comment: Any correct XML parser (e.g. XML::LibXML) will handle a valid document encoded using UTF-16. Could you provide more information please?

Comment: @ikegam the question is asking (albeit not as clearly as it could) how to *create* an xml file in utf-16 encoding

Comment: @ysth, My earlier comment applies to generators as well. (Except woops, XML::Writer doesn't support UTF-16.) Anyway, the main point that we need to know how the OP is creating the document before going any further definitely still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if the following sample code complies with your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw/encode decode/;

my $filename = 'utf16_1.txt';

open my($out), '>:encoding(UTF-16LE)', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename";

my $string = 'Sample data';

print $out $string; 

close($out);
```

other variation

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw/encode decode/;

my $filename = 'utf16_2.txt';

open my($out), '>:raw', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename";

my $string = 'Sample data';

print $out encode("UTF-16LE", $string); 

close($out);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .
Please can you help find a suitable model for the xml I create to support Hebrew
I try to write to a file in Hebrew and return incorrect characters Gibrish, but in analogue it writes me excellent
Thank you if you can help me with this

Comment: In your question you did not specify your final goal. Do you create **xml** file to store data or you use somehow other way (for example post content on the website). If you store data in **xml** file then some software will read it and you have referred to **UTF-16LE** which is a specific of this software. If you publish data on a website then **utf8** should be sufficient. Could you be more specific on **what is return incorrect characters Gibrish**?

Comment: Please visit following [The Hebrew University of Jerusalem](https://new.huji.ac.il/) and in browser active window press **Ctrl+U** to see the source of the webpage. You will see what **XML** doctype this website set to use -- probably it is what you need.

Comment: Hi, the ultimate goal is to store data in Excel file in utf-16le format and the data in the file will be in Hebrew.

Comment: Save the data in [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format and open it in the _Excel_ for further processing. You need to confirm that _Excel_ expects imported data in **UTF8** encoding.

Comment: I don't understand you so why save in excal I need to do data storage in xml file when this data is in Hebrew language, the system is currently live in live environment and it supports English only so my requirement is to change format to utf16le and write into the file in Hebrew language

Comment: @Eden ohana -- you wrote _Hi, the ultimate goal is to store data in Excel file in utf-16le format and the data in the file will be in Hebrew_. Now you say that you do not store in _Excel_! Otherwise retrieve data and store it in **UTF-16LE** in XML file [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) -- sample of my code showed how to switch to **UTF-16LE** encoding.

Comment: You were wrong in writing the iPhone repair.  Anyway tomorrow I will send you some of my code and some sample xml and then maybe you can understand me better

Comment: the ultimate goal is to store data in the utf-16le XML file and the data in the file will be in Hebrew